# how to prevent input type from being definite type?

Tags: c, cs50

i am including cs50 library in my circle calculator so i can get get input from user about operation(circumference/area/volume)then radius,so i want to make sure that first input is number from 1 to 3 by displaying "please enter a number from 1 to 3" in other conditions but i can't handle the else statement as the question "please choose operation:" is declared as float so it only accept floats or it will just start over(only numbers except 1,2,3 will cause the else statement not letters)
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
    
void get_circum(float radius);
void get_area(float radius);
void get_volume(float radius);

int main (void){
    printf("welcome in circle calculator,please select operation! \n");
    int operation = get_int("1-circumference \n2-area \n3-volume \n");
    if(operation==1 || operation==2 || operation==3){
        float radius = get_float("radius: \n");
        if(operation==1){get_circum(radius);}
        else if(operation==2){get_area(radius);}
        else if(operation==3){get_volume(radius);}
    }
    else if(operation !=1 && operation !=2 && operation !=3){
        printf("please enter a number from 1 to 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: *cs50* questions is probably better to ask at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you want a value that is a 1, 2, or 3, why are you reading it into a float in the first place?

Comment: I don't know the first thing about cs50, but when I want to prompt my user for input, I usually use stuff like `scanf("%d\n", &operation);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to loop until the user enters a number between `1` and `3`, then I recommend that you use an infinite loop and explicitly `break` out of the loop once you determine that the input is valid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
    
void get_circum(float radius);
void get_area(float radius);
void get_volume(float radius);

int main( void )
{
    int operation;

    printf( "Welcome to circle calculator, please select operation! \n");

    //loop forever until input is valid    
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        operation = get_int( "1-circumference \n2-area \n3-volume \n" );

        if ( operation == 1 || operation == 2 || operation == 3 )
        {
            //input is ok, so break out of infinite loop
            break;
        }

        printf( "Invalid input! Please enter a number from 1 to 3!\n" );
    }
    
    float radius = get_float("radius: \n");
    if      ( operation == 1 ) {get_circum(radius);}
    else if ( operation == 2 ) {get_area(radius);}
    else if ( operation == 3 ) {get_volume(radius);}
}
```